# How to talk into a microphone on one computer and have it output the audio on a remote computer over the internet?

Tags: audio, remote, microphone

So let's say I decided to dress up as a ghost for Halloween. I hook up a speaker to my work machine, and then don't come in to work at all that day. Then while I am actually working remote I can talk into a microphone from my home PC and have it output through that speaker in my office. So then I can be like "I am here, I am just in my ghost costume".

Comment: Any messaging software (like good old Windows Live Messenger or Skype) should do the trick. You would need to have an active connection at all times though.

Comment: Skype, Google Hangouts, even Facebook all do this.

Comment: See that's the thing I am trying to avoid, I don't want to have to be on the machine to 'answer' a call, I want to initiate it entirely remotely... might have to write my own plugin or something.

Comment: But still, something needs to answer your request to "talk" to your remote machine. From the top of my mind TeamViewer could give you the access you needed, but you would still need to have the session up on both.

Comment: VLC can do multicasting over the web as long as you forward ports correctly. I'm not sure how it can interface with a microphone, though.